# Raspberry Pi Login Error - Login incorrect

Tags: authentication, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi running raspbian that I can no longer login to. I have been using the "pi" user without any problems up to this point. However, when it asks for a login and I input "pi", I get an error that says "Login Incorrect" and am asked for a login again. This happens at the command line as I was working on setting it up as a headless file server.

This doesn't happen if I give it the username "root". If I try to login as "root", it asks for a password but no password seems to work. I tried looking up the default "root" password and found that the "root" user is not enabled on the pi.

Strangely, if I try to access the pi via ssh (using PuTTY), I can login as the user "pi". However, as soon as I do the connection is broken with the error: "Server unexpectedly closed network connection".

What could be happening to cause this? Do I have any way of fixing the problem if I can't login?

Some background as to what might have caused this:

I was working on setting up Deluge with it's Web UI. However, deluge doesn't have init scripts so I was following [this](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/systemd) guide to create the init scripts. My pi didn't have "systemctl" installed so I started following [this](http://blog.higgsboson.tk/2012/09/19/systemd-on-raspbian/) guide to install "systemctl". I had a problem after editing "/boot/cmdline.txt" which caused my pi to boot into safe mode. I removed my edits and the pi booted normally again.

I don't know if any of my above attempts could have caused my login problems but essentially the only thing I was doing was trying to setup deluge when I stopped being able to login.

Answer (score 2):

Login as root and type:

```
passwd pi
```

And that will allow you to set a new password for user pi. if not, re install raspbian to your SD card. Works everytime.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're not able to login but I would suggest using the Deluge client instead of the WebUI as it has more features - you can get it from [here](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Download)

You can find a good step-by-step tutorial of how to use Deluge with a client [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/142044/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-always-on-bittorrent-box/)

In the meantime I might be inclined to start from scratch with a fresh Wheezy install instead of wasting too much time on it..

Comment: The main reason I was planning on using the WebUI is so that my wife can access it on her phone. She uses her phone much more than any computer. I have done a few other things with the pi, such as setting up a file and print server so I was hoping to not have to start fresh but I will if I have to. Thanks for the help.